# SetTimeout and setInterval the first parameter plus no parentheses, plus no double quotes

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var num=0;
function numCount(){
 document.getElementById('txt').value=num;
 num=num+1;
 setTimeout(numCount(),1000);
 }

</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<input type="text" id="txt" />
<input type="button" value="Start" onClick="numCount()" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Why do you want to add parentheses to the first parameter in the above code, and why do you add a double quotation mark in the seTimeout? What about setInterval?

Comment: You don't want to add parentheses. `numCount` doesn't return anything. And what "double quotation marks"?

Comment: Is setTimeout ("numcount"), 1000);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to :

```
setTimeout(numCount,1000);
```

With the `()` you are invoking the function immediately. Above is passing the function as a reference and it will be called after the delay time.

The other less preferred way using quotes is:

```
setTimeout('numCount()',1000); // or setTimeout("numCount()",1000);
```

Using string argument.. the string will be evaluated as script at end of timer delay

When in doubt look it up in the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout)

Comment: Oh, that's what he meant by quotes. Honestly, I thought only PHP allowed that.

Comment: @Carcigenicate it basically gets compiled similar to `eval()` internally if it is string

Comment: Ya. I can't see why you'd possibly want to do that; seems like it would encourage brittle code. Passing a function reference just makes a lot more sense.

Comment: 所以setInterval与setTimeout相同？

Comment: what are you asking?

Comment: Because I see a few cases, setTimeout and setInterval in the "plus" () or direct "function name", so I do not know, can not understand

Comment: @HopeVerse Just don't use `"`s. Give `setTimeout` a function, without calling it. And what do you mean `"plus"`? Show an example.

Comment: such as     setTimeout(“numCount()”,1000);   Double quotation marks

Comment: There are 2 ways ... string code or function. Read the documentation link in my answer